# Using IntelliJ IDEA with Maven projects that use the "generate-sources" or "process-classes" lifecycle phases

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm working on a *Maven* project that uses a plugins bound to the `generate-sources` and `process-classes` lifecycle phases. When the project is imported into *IntelliJ IDEA*, IDEA takes over compilation of the project sources and does so according to the settings in the `pom.xml`. But it does not implement any of the other lifecycle phases. How can I get these other lifecycle phases to be executed when building the project from within IntelliJ IDEA?

I know that I can create a run configuration that specifically runs Maven with the `process-classes` phase and then set this run configuration up to run before other configurations, but that will build all modules and not just the modules necessary for that particular run configuration, besides it taking an order of magnitude longer than a build from with IntelliJ IDEA. Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you try to set up the execution of a phase "before Make" (see here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-triggers-for-maven-goals.html)?

Comment: @Tome Hmm, that looks promising but it look like I can only do that for a selection of lifecycle phases. For example, I can't see the phase `generate-sources`.

Comment: There is an option in the Maven tool windows to show more than just the basic phases, see here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-projects-tool-window.html

Comment: I had a similar issue with androidannotations generating sources for an android app. I couldn't find anything helpful unfortunately to do what you are asking

Comment: Is it a custom plugin or is it from a third party? If it's something like Lombok, then there may be a corresponding IntelliJ plugin that will automatically execute the phases that you need. Or you could create an IntelliJ plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only two options for the maven Lifecycle in IntelliJ are Basic and Full (**Cog** -> untick **Show Basic Phases Only**).

If you are happy with it running the full suite of phases you can just run the full set, but otherwise the best option is just to add all the appropriate ones to a run configuration and run that on its own.